# save crontab output to a new file everytime?

Tags: centos, logging, cron

I want to save my crontab output:

```
15 * * * * myscript.sh > ~/logs/log1.txt
```

How do i make the crontab save to a new file everytime (i.e. log2.txt, log3.txt etc.) , instead of updating or overwriting the old one?

Perhaps there's a utility i could use to do this?

I'm using CENT OS 5.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have a look at [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/how-to-add-unique-id-to-file-name-in-cron-job).

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) and time to make a unique file name

```
15 * * * * myscript.sh > ~/logs/log.$(/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

This will create files named like  `~/logs/log.20110426121501.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
if you can't use the date as answered by Iain
from your script output a watermark like ### 
this is what I have into test.txt

###
test
###
test1

then to process it 
shell$ awk -F "###"  {'print $1'} test.txt

test

test1

i have the delimiter changed from ' ' into awk to '###' and then just print the lines
```